# android studio detect no device when i plug my phone

Tags: android, android-studio, virtual-machine, device

I am using Android Studio 3.5.3 . I can not see my device to run.
before ( last version ) it did work, but now just work with NOX.

- I check my phone setting (USB debugging....)
- I try to go to run --> edit configurations but after I don't know what should I do
  [my android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iBCj.png)

[my android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sql0v.png)

[my android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdTY8.png)

Comment: Try writing `adb kill-server` in the terminal while the devices are connected. Disconnect the devices and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:
*File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
*Change your Cable Data
*Restart your PC

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure your mobile device developer option is enabled. then check the usb debugging option. and verify the system have configured USB Drivers properly else use some third party tools to install those drives. it will work once drive install.